# Best way to copy 20Gb csv file to cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, sqoop, flume, cqlsh

I have a huge 20Gb csv file to copy into cassandra, of course i need to manage the case of errors ( if the the server or the Transfer/Load application crashes ).

I need to re-start the processing(or an other node or not) and continue the transfer without starting the csv file from it begning.

what is the best and easiest way to do that ?

using the Copy CQLSH Command ? using flume or sqoop ? or using native java application, using spark... ?

thanks a lot

Comment: i'd like to accept both of the answers above, but unfortunately i can't

Answer (score 2):

If it was me, I would split the file.

I would pick a preferred way to load any csv data in, ignoring the issues of huge file size and error handling. For example, I would use a python script and the native driver and test it with a few lines of csv to see that it can insert from a tiny csv file with real data.

Then I would write a script to split the file into manageable sized chunks, however you define it. I would try a few chunk sizes to get a file size that loads in about a minute. Maybe you will need hundreds of chunks for 20 GB, but probably not thousands.

Then I would split the whole file into chunks of that size and loop over the chunks, logging how it is going. On an error of any kind, fix the problem and just start loading again from the last chunk that loaded successfully as found in the log file.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, i think this is what CQLSH Copy command do no ?

Comment: I was not aware of the cqlsh utility before now. The docs do not mention error recovery and restarting from the middle, but it might be a simple way to load in chunks of your large file.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a two considerations that I would try first since they are simple and well contained:

1. cqlsh COPY has been [vastly improved](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-features-in-cqlsh-copy) in 2.1.13, 2.2.5, 3.0.3 and 3.2+.  If you do consider using it, make sure to be at one of those versions or newer.
2. Another option is to use Brian Hess' [cassandra-loader](https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader) which is an effective way of bulk loading to and from csv files in an efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

I think CQLSH doesn't handle the case of application crash, so why not using both of the solution exposed above, split the file into several manageable chunks and uses the copy cqlsh command to import the data ?